# Vroid textures messed up. I don't know why

Tags: text-object

Ok, I'm trying to do some bone work on my [VRoid](https://vroid.com/en) model aka a VRM, but every time I press fix it (with the [cat blender plugin](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin)) it gives me a monster of a model and I don't know what to do.

[image: VRoid model showing problem]

Comment: We are probably going to need to look at a blend file to figure this one out. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: what fille? im still pretty new to blender

Comment: the .blend file that has the model in it.